# Regular expression for date doesn't match in python's RE module

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently writing a piece of code to extract data from a list of observation sites (an example is given below). I currently have a list of regular expressions to remove any lines which don't contain data I'm looking for. All of the regular expressions successfully indicate the lines on which metadata is contained except for the one searching for the date. When tested at regexr.com, the expression works just fine, but when running code, I am unable to remove the lines. What am I missing to remove the lines containing dates?

Example of data

```
!   CD = 2 letter state (province) abbreviation
!   STATION = 16 character station long name
!   ICAO = 4-character international id
!   IATA = 3-character (FAA) id
!   SYNOP = 5-digit international synoptic number
!   LAT = Latitude (degrees minutes)
!   LON = Longitude (degree minutes)
!   ELEV = Station elevation (meters)
!   M = METAR reporting station.   Also Z=obsolete? site
!   N = NEXRAD (WSR-88D) Radar site
!   V = Aviation-specific flag (V=AIRMET/SIGMET end point, A=ARTCC T=TAF U=T+V)
!   U = Upper air (rawinsonde=X) or Wind Profiler (W) site
!   A = Auto (A=ASOS, W=AWOS, M=Meso, H=Human, G=Augmented) (H/G not yet impl.)
!   C = Office type F=WFO/R=RFC/C=NCEP Center
!   Digit that follows is a priority for plotting (0=highest)
!   Country code (2-char) is last column
!
!2345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890                                                                                                  1234567890
!

ALASKA             16-DEC-13
CD  STATION         ICAO  IATA  SYNOP   LAT     LONG   ELEV   M  N  V  U  A  C
AK ADAK NAS         PADK  ADK   70454  51 53N  176 39W    4   X     T          7                                                                                                   US
AK AKHIOK           PAKH  AKK          56 56N  154 11W   14   X                8                                                                                                   US
AK AMBLER           PAFM  AFM          67 06N  157 51W   88   X                7                                                                                                   US
AK ANAKTUVUK PASS   PAKP  AKP          68 08N  151 44W  642   X                7                                                                                                   US
AK ANCHORAGE INTL   PANC  ANC   70273  61 10N  150 01W   38   X     T  X  A    5                                                                                                   US
AK ANCHORAGE/WFO    PAFC  AFC          61 10N  150 02W   48                  F 8                                                                                                   US
AK ANCHORAG/NIKISKI PAHG  AHG          60 44N  151 21W   74      X             8                                                                                                   US
AK ANCHORAGE/LAKE H PALH  LHD          61 11N  149 58W   22   X           A    7                                                                                                   US
AK ANCHORAGE/ARTCC  PZAN  ZAN          61 10N  149 59W   22         A          8                                                                                                   US
AK ANCHORAGE/MERRIL PAMR  MRI          61 13N  149 51W   41   X           A    7                                                                                                   US
AK ANGOON SEAPLANE  PAGN               57 30N  134 35W    2   X                8                                                                                                   US
AK ANIAK            PANI  ANI   70232  61 35N  159 32W   26   X                7                                                                                                   US
AK ANNETTE ISLAND   PANT  ANN   70398  55 02N  131 34W   36   X        X  A    5                                                                                                   US
AK ANVIK            PANV  ANV          62 39N  160 11W   99   X                7                                                                                                   US
AK ARCTIC VILLAGE   PARC  ARC          68 07N  145 35W  636   X                7                                                                                                   US
AK ATQASUK BURNELL  PATQ  ATK          70 28N  157 26W   29   X                7                                                                                                   US
AK ATKA             PAAK  AKA          52 13N  174 12W   17   X                7                                                                                                   US
AK BARROW           PABR  BRW   70026  71 17N  156 48W    7   X     T  X  A    5                                                                                                   US
AK BARROW ARM-NSA               70027  71 19N  156 37W    7            X       8                                                                                                   US
AK BARTER ISLAND    PABA  BTI   70086  70 08N  143 35W    2   X           W    7                                                                                                   US
AK BETHEL           PABE  BET   70219  60 47N  161 51W   41   X     T  X  A    5                                                                                                   US
AK BETHEL/88D       PABC  ABC          60 48N  161 53W   49      X             8                                                                                                   US
AK BETTLES          PABT  BTT   70174  66 55N  151 31W  195   X     T     A    6                                                                                                   US
AK BIG RIVER LAKES  PALV  LVR          60 49N  152 18W   12   X                7                                                                                                   US
AK BIRCHWOOD        PABV  BCV          61 25N  149 31W   29   X                7                                                                                                   US
AK BREVIG_MISSION   PFKT               65 20N  166 28W    9   X                7                                                                                                   US
AK BUCKLAND         PABL  BVK          65 59N  161 09W    7   X                7                                                                                                   US
AK CANTWELL         PATW  TTW          63 23N  148 57W  668   X                7                                                                                                   US
AK CAPE LISBURNE    PALU  LUR   70104  68 53N  166 08W    3   X     T     W    6                                                                                                   US
AK CAPE NEWENHAM    PAEH  EHM   70305  58 39N  162 04W  161   X     T          6                                                                                                   US
AK CAPE ROMANZOF    PACZ  CZF   70212  61 47N  166 02W  146   X     T          6                                                                                                   US
AK CENTRAL          PARL               65 34N  144 47W  284   X                7                                                                                                   US
AK CENTRAL          PACE               65 34N  144 47W  286   X                7                                                                                                   US
AK CENTRAL AK PROF        CEN   70197  65 30N  144 41W  259            W       8                                                                                                   US
AK CHANDALAR LAKE   PALR  WCR          67 30N  148 29W  585   X                7                                                                                                   US
AK CHEVAK           PAVA               61 32N  165 36W   23   X                7                                                                                                   US
AK CHIGNIK BAY      PAJC  AJC          56 19N  158 22W   15   X                7                                                                                                   US
AK CIRCLE/PAFC RFC  PACR  CRC          65 50N  144 04W  182   X              R 7                                                                                                   US
AK COLD BAY         PACD  CDB   70316  55 12N  162 43W   30   X     T  X  A    5                                                                                                   US
AK CORDOVA          PACV  CDV   70296  60 30N  145 30W   12   X     T     A    6                                                                                                   US
AK DEADHORSE        PASC  SCC          70 12N  148 28W   15   X     T     A    6                                                                                                   US
AK DEERING          PADE  DEE          66 04N  162 46W    5   X           A    7                                                                                                   US
AK DELTA JUNCTION   PABI  BIG   70267  64 00N  145 44W  386   X     T     A    6                                                                                                   US
```

My Code

```
station_file = open('../DATA/stations.txt', 'r')
data = station_file.read()

skip_res = ['^$', '^.*d{2}\-[A-Z]{3}\-\d{2}','^!'] #List of regular expressions which only appear in lines of metadata (not actual data)

data = data.split('\n')

for loop in data:
    breakcheck = False # In the event a regular expression matches, this will turn to true and skip that line
    for check in skip_res:
        current = re.compile(check)
        if current.search(loop) == None:
            continue
        else:
            breakcheck = True
            break
    if breakcheck:
        continue
    else:
        print(loop) # Should only print out lines containing actual data.
```

Comment: Just a note, I tried the regex without the caret, escaped hyphen all before posting this. This just happened to be the last thing I tried before consulting the internet for help.

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern for matching the date is missing a `\` before the first `d`. Change it to:

```
r'\d{2}-[A-Z]{3}-\d{2}'
```

Since you are using `re.search()` you don't need to match from the beginning of the string. Also, you don't need to escape the `-`.

Note the use a a raw string (denoted by the `r` prefix) to specify the pattern. Generally you should use raw strings for regex patterns because there are some string escape sequences that are also regex patterns, e.g. `\b`. As a normal string this represents the backspace character. In a raw string it is treated as `\` followed by `b` which is the regex pattern for "beginning or end of a word".

Another thing worth mentioning is that you can check for a match of more than one pattern at at time by joining the patterns together with `|`. Think of it as "or". Then your code can be written more concisely:

```
skip_res = [r'^$', r'\d{2}-[A-Z]{3}-\d{2}',r'^!']
skip_pattern = r'|'.join(skip_res)

with open ('../DATA/stations.txt', 'r') as station_file:
    for line in station_file:
        if re.search(skip_pattern, line):
            continue
        print(line)
```

Compiling the regex pattern provides no benefit when there are only a handful of them because the `re` module will cache them.

Answer (score 0):

Your date regex is missing a backslash before the first "d".

```
'^.*d{2}\-[A-Z]{3}\-\d{2}'
```

should be

```
'^.*\d{2}\-[A-Z]{3}\-\d{2}'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Not sure how I missed that!